# Ending my secret word game and outputting user guess count in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I am attempting to code a Hangman-like word game in Python.
There is no limit to how many times the user can guess.

I have the game working correctly except for one small problem:
when the user guesses the full word, the game doesn't end and tell them that they won, and how many guesses it took.

```
def main():

    print("Welcome to the Secret Word Game!")
    print()


    word = ["m","o","u","n","t","a","i","n"]

    guessed = []
    wrong = []

    guesses = 0

    while True:

        out = ""
        for letter in word:
            if letter in guessed:
                out = out + letter
            else:
                out = out + "*"

        if out == word:
            print("You guessed", word)
            break

        print("Guess a letter from the secret word:", out)

        guess = input()

        if guess in guessed or guess in wrong:
            print("Already guessed", guess)
            guesses +=1
        elif guess in word:
            print("Correct!",guess,"is in the secret word!")
            guessed.append(guess)
            guesses+=1
        else:
            print("Wrong!")
            wrong.append(guess)
            guesses+=1

    print()
    print(guesses)




main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't exit because it's impossible for your termination condition to be True:

```
    if out == word:
```

`out` is a string of length 8; `word` is a list of 8 one-character strings.  If you change the initialization of `word` to

```
    word = "mountain"
```

Then your program works fine, producing the guess-by-guess updates and the proper quantity of guesses.

```
Welcome to the Secret Word Game!

Guess a letter from the secret word: ********
n
Correct! n is in the secret word!
Guess a letter from the secret word: ***n***n
e
Wrong!
Guess a letter from the secret word: ***n***n
t
Correct! t is in the secret word!
Guess a letter from the secret word: ***nt**n
a
Correct! a is in the secret word!
Guess a letter from the secret word: ***nta*n
o
Correct! o is in the secret word!
Guess a letter from the secret word: *o*nta*n
i
Correct! i is in the secret word!
Guess a letter from the secret word: *o*ntain
f
Wrong!
Guess a letter from the secret word: *o*ntain
m
Correct! m is in the secret word!
Guess a letter from the secret word: mo*ntain
u
Correct! u is in the secret word!
You guessed mountain

9
```